# Flutter Modular redirect to 404 page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, flutter-plugin

I used [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular) for flutter web to navigation.

```
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';

 class AppModule extends Module {
   @override
   final List<Bind> binds = [];

   @override
   final List<ModularRoute> routes = [
       ChildRoute('/', child: (_, __) => HomeScreen()),
       ChildRoute('/signin', child: (_, __) => SignInPage()),
       ChildRoute('/login', child: (_, __) => LogInPage()),
       ChildRoute('/404', child: (_, __) => Custome404()),
  ];
 }
```

if unfortunately user typed URL like `example.com/gfhgfhb/`.
The flutter modular plugin show error `Error: RouteNotFoundException: Route (/rferwg) not found`. Now who can I set default 404 page in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use WildcardRoute :

```
WildcardRoute(child: (context, args) => NotFoundPage()),
```

according to its [documentation](https://modular.flutterando.com.br/docs/flutter_modular/navegation/#wildcardroute) :

> Have only one WildcardRoute per module and, if possible, let it be the
> last element.

Comment: You are awesome man, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a `MaterialApp`, `CupertinoApp`, or `WidgetsApp` somewhere ? If so, you could use the `onUnknownRoute` property:

```
onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageNotFound());
},
```

https://medium.com/flutter/handling-404-page-not-found-error-in-flutter-731f5a9fba29